# Find point covered by all given circles

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, algorithms

Given is $n$ circles ($n \le 1000$) circles where the $x$- and $y$-coordinates of their centers, and their radii, are all at most $10^6$.

The problem is to find a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ covered by all circles, or to determine that there is no such point.

Comment: I think (and edited your problem to say) specifically that you are looking for *a* point, rather than, say, a description of the set of all such points.  Presumably the problem is to find an efficient (how efficient?) *algorithm* to do this; either such a point exists or it doesn't, so, without giving some precise meaning to 'determine', the problem seems hard to understand.

Comment: Also, since you have given a fixed number of circles, it's hard to know how to measure the efficiency of the algorithm, so I guess 1000 was just for fun.  The bound on the sizes of $x$- and $y$-coordinates and of radii seems superfluous, since the problem can be scaled to make all of those as small as desired.

Comment: The Aurenhammer paper I cited achieves $O(n \log n)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use [Helly's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_theorem):
$n \ge 3$ convex sets in the plane have a common intersection if and only if
every three of the sets intersects.

There are faster algorithms:

> Aurenhammer, Franz. "Improved algorithms for discs and balls using power diagrams." *Journal of Algorithms* 9, no. 2 (1988): 151-161.
> [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1016/0196-6774(88)90035-1).

---

*Later edit*. I found this nice figure in answer to an MSE question,
[the intersection of n disks/circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/225089/237):

[image: Disks]

Comment: I can determine if there is an intersection using Helly's theorem, yes, but I can't find any point inside the intersection, can I?

Comment: Ok, you helped, ty <3